# Manyfoot margins, conflict with \newgeometry

Tags: margins, geometry, manyfoot

I need one part of a book to have wider margins than the rest. (I know that this is non-standard, but this part is a translation of a text that has large marginal notes.) Furthermore, this part of the text has multiple layers of footnotes, which I am implementing with manyfoot.

I tried a number of different ways to use the geometry package's \newgeometry to control the margins, but the manyfoot footnotes do not conform to the margins when I use \newgeometry. (I also tried using the quoting package to define a new environment, but this did not work because leftmargin and rightmargin are absolute, and do not function as inner and outer margins. I also tried changepage and adjustwidth, but this did not work either.)

Here is a MWE showing the problem with manyfoot and \newgeometry:

```
\documentclass{book} 

\usepackage[para*]{manyfoot}
\newfootnote[para]{C}
\newcounter{footnoteC} 
\newcommand{\footnoteC}{%
\stepcounter{footnoteC}%
\linespread{1.2}% Set line spacing
\Footnotemark\thefootnoteC \FootnotetextC\thefootnoteC}

\newfootnote[para]{T}
\newcounter{footnoteT}
\newcommand{\footnoteT}{%
        \stepcounter{footnoteT}%
\linespread{1.2}% Set line spacing
        \Footnotemark\thefootnoteT \FootnotetextT\thefootnoteT}
     \renewcommand{\thefootnoteT}{\alph{footnoteT}}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
inner=30mm, 
outer=40mm,
top=20mm, 
headsep=1.78mm, 
bottom=30mm
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Chapter 1}
%
Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah.\footnoteC{~\lipsum[35]% 
}
Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah.\footnoteT{~\lipsum[46]% 
}
\lipsum[1-2]
Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah.\footnoteT{\,~%
\lipsum[50]% 
}
%
\lipsum[78]
Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah.\footnote{~\lipsum[35]% 
}
%
\lipsum[18-19]
Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah.\footnoteC{~\lipsum[89]% 
}
\lipsum[8]

% I want to change just the outer margin and leave the inner margin the same as the rest of the book.

\globaldefs=1
\newgeometry{%
inner=30mm, %
outer=60mm% 
}
\globaldefs=0

\chapter*{Chapter 2}
Blah blah blah blahblah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
} 
blah blahblahblah Blah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahbla.\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
BlahBlah blah blah blahblah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
} 
blah blahblahblah Blah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah.\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
} 
blahblahblah.\footnoteT{~\lipsum[46]% 
}
\lipsum[1-2]
Blah blahblah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
} 
blah blahblahblah Blah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahbla.\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
BlahBlah blah blah blahblah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
} 
blah blahblahblah Blah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
 blahblahblah.\footnoteT{\,~%
\lipsum[50]% 
}
%
\lipsum[78]
Blah blah blah blahblah Blah blah blah blahblah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
} 
blah blahblahblah Blah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahbla.\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
BlahBlah blah blah blahblah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
} 
blah blahblahblah Blah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
 blahblahblah.\footnoteT{~\lipsum[35]% 
}
%
\lipsum[18] blahblah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
} 
blah blahblahblah Blah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahbla.\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
BlahBlah blah blah blahblah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
} 
blah blahblahblah Blah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah\footnoteC{~blahblah blah blahblahblah.% 
}
 blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah.

\restoregeometry




\chapter*{Chapter 3}
%
Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah.\footnoteC{~\lipsum[35]% 
}
Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah.\footnoteT{~\lipsum[46]% 
}
\lipsum[1-2]
Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah.\footnoteT{\,~%
\lipsum[50]% 
}
%
\lipsum[78]
Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah.\footnote{~\lipsum[35]% 
}
%
\lipsum[18-19]
Blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah Blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblahblah.\footnoteC{~\lipsum[89]% 
}
\lipsum[8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can see that on the odd pages the footnotes jut out into the outer margin, but even worse, on the even pages, the footnotes are flush with the outer margin and jut into the inner margin. (It might be an acceptable option that the header, footer, and footnotes remain the same throughout the whole book and only the margins of the main text change, but the actual result is completely unacceptable.)

I also tried using the geometry package to write a new environment, as follows:

```
\newenvironment{translation}
  {
  \globaldefs=1 % This has no effect
   \newgeometry{
    inner=30mm, %bindingoffset=6mm,% The inner margin is the sum of these. 
    outer=60mm
    }
   \globaldefs=0 % This has no effect
   \aftergroup
   \restoregeometry
  }
```

But the result was the same as in the MWE given above.

Does anyone know how I can pass the new textwidth to manyfoot? Or how to make \newgeometry function at the base level and pass its parameters to manyfoot? Notice that the original margins set by the geometry package itself are passed to manyfoot, so it seems to be possible in principle.

Comment: Add `\makeatletter \MFL@columnwidth\columnwidth \makeatother` when you change the geometry. And remove the \globaldefs settings, you should never use that unless you control all the code in its scope, which you don't do here, as \newgeometry issues a \newpage and so calls the output routine.

Comment: Great! That worked. Thanks for the tip about \globaldefs as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
 \makeatletter \MFL@columnwidth\columnwidth \makeatother
```

when you change the geometry to update the columnwidth of the footnotes.

And remove the `\globaldefs` settings, you should never use that unless you control *all* the code in its scope, which you don't do here, as `\newgeometry` issues a `\newpage` and so calls the output routine. When I tried your example I ended up with missing backslashes in the aux-file because of this.